# How on earth select * from alphabet returns just one row when there are thousands?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have double checked everything in my table. I have already about 40,000 records in the words table.

What I have done:

```
const DB_HOST='localhost';
const DB_NAME='games';
const DB_USER='postgres';
const DB_PASS='1234';
$instance = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$schemas = '"alphabet","public","grammars"';
$instance->exec("SET search_path TO $schemas");    
$stmt = $instance->prepare('SELECT word FROM alphabet');
$stmt->execute();
$words = $stmt->fetch();
```

Now in $words I just have the first record!  When I put this query `SELECT word FROM alphabet` in phppgAdmin then all 40,000 words will be returned.

Is there anything that I've missed here. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**NB:** I've debugged my code with netbeans line by line, so I'm pretty sure that just one record has been returned.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php): Fetches the next row from a result set.

[fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php): Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

So what you need here is fetchAll or use fetch in a loop.

```
$words = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use fetchAll() to return all items. fetch() will return the first record and is used to loop through all records one at the time such as:

```
 while($data = $stmt->fetch()){}
```